# How to make website footer stay at the bottom of the page?

Tags: html, css, footer, sticky-footer

I am relatively new to HTML and CSS, and I know this question has been asked many times. But I haven't found a solution that works. My project partner sent me this HTML footer code which I have to put at the bottom of our website. The lone HTML file itself works when I open it on a browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.footer-dark {
  padding:50px 0;
  color:#f0f9ff;
  background-color:#0a384b;
}
.footer-dark h3 {
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:16px;
}
.footer-dark ul {
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  line-height:1.6;
  font-size:14px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
.footer-dark ul a {
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  opacity:0.6;
}
.footer-dark ul a:hover {
  opacity:0.8;
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .footer-dark .item:not(.social) {
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }
}
.footer-dark .item.text {
  margin-bottom:36px;
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .footer-dark .item.text {
    margin-bottom:0;
  }
}
.footer-dark .item.text p {
  opacity:0.6;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
.footer-dark .item.social {
  text-align:center;
}
@media (max-width:991px) {
  .footer-dark .item.social {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:20px;
  }
}
.footer-dark .item.social > a {
  font-size:20px;
  width:36px;
  height:36px;
  line-height:36px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  margin:0 8px;
  color:#fff;
  opacity:0.75;
}
.footer-dark .item.social > a:hover {
  opacity:0.9;
}
.footer-dark .copyright {
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:24px;
  opacity:0.3;
  font-size:13px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
</style>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Untitled</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="footer-dark">
      <footer>
          <div class="container">
              <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">
                      <h3>Services</h3>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">Consultation</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Confinement</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Other Services</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 item">
                      <h3>About</h3>
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="#">Doctors</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Partner Hospitals</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">Offers</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-6 item text">
                      <h3>St. San Vitores Hospital</h3>
                      <p>Your health is our priority. </p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col item social"><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-facebook"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-twitter"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-snapchat"></i></a><a href="#"><i class="icon ion-social-instagram"></i></a></div>
              </div>
              <p class="copyright">St. San Vitores Hospital © 1980 </p>
          </div>
      </footer>
  </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

However, I have to incorporate his code into our main file. I put the contents inside < div class="footer-dark" > in our index.html file, and the content inside the < style > tag in our index.css file.

**CSS**

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
    .container a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
    }
    .header-right {
      float: none;
    }
  }
html {
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
body {
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;

  display:flex; 
  flex-direction:column; 
}

/* other content of the website*/

footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;   /* Height of the footer */
    background:#6cf;
}
.footer-dark {
  padding:50px 0;
  color:#f0f9ff;
  background-color:#0a384b;
}
.footer-dark h3 {
  margin-top:0;
  margin-bottom:12px;
  font-weight:bold;
  font-size:16px;
}
.footer-dark ul {
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  line-height:1.6;
  font-size:14px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
.footer-dark ul a {
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  opacity:0.6;
}
.footer-dark ul a:hover {
  opacity:0.8;
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .footer-dark .item:not(.social) {
    text-align:center;
    padding-bottom:20px;
  }
}
.footer-dark .item.text {
  margin-bottom:36px;
}
@media (max-width:767px) {
  .footer-dark .item.text {
    margin-bottom:0;
  }
}
.footer-dark .item.text p {
  opacity:0.6;
  margin-bottom:0;
}
.footer-dark .item.social {
  text-align:center;
}
@media (max-width:991px) {
  .footer-dark .item.social {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top:20px;
  }
}
.footer-dark .item.social > a {
  font-size:20px;
  width:36px;
  height:36px;
  line-height:36px;
  display:inline-block;
  text-align:center;
  border-radius:50%;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.4);
  margin:0 8px;
  color:#fff;
  opacity:0.75;
}
.footer-dark .item.social > a:hover {
  opacity:0.9;
}
.footer-dark .copyright {
  text-align:center;
  padding-top:24px;
  opacity:0.3;
  font-size:13px;
  margin-bottom:0;
}

html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

The footer contents overlap some contents in the middle of the webpage. However, when I minimize the browser, the footer actually goes to the bottom. How do I make it stay at the bottom of the webpage regardless of the size of the browser?

Answer (score 0):

From html and also from the index.css it works for me by adding these 2 lines to .footer-dark:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;  
width: 100%;
```

And remember

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
```

in the head section of your html.

Comment: still in the middle of the page. But thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the fixed position and the bottom style to your footer-dark class

```css
.footer-dark {
  padding:50px 0;
  color:#f0f9ff;
  background-color:#0a384b;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
}
```